# Trying to add an image/icon just before the text in a section while using moderncv

Tags: graphics, moderncv, sharelatex

Note: I'm using [`sharelatex`](http://www.sharelatex.com)

I was wondering if there are any way to set the background color of the header part (the one that contains personal info) of a file that uses [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) in order to visually differentiate the header and the content.

I tried with `minipage`, `\hfill` and so on but I guess that `moderncv` uses a heavily customized template and everything I've tried so far lead to a compile error.

```
\section{\includegraphics{../static/32x32/image.png}Expériences Professionnelles}
```

The error:

```
Error in fr/source.tex (line 54): Use of \@newline doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                              #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.54 ...image.png}Expériences Professionnelles}

If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.
```

Comment: The title of thq question talks about an image or icon before a section, but the body of the question talks about a background color (which was asked before and has been answered in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163905/3954).

Comment: Where should the image appear? Before the colored bar, between the bar and the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option. I redefined `\section` as implemented for the `classic` style so now you have a third optional argument allowing you to place anything (in particular, an image) before the section:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\firstname{John} 
\familyname{Smith}

\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{Street}{City, St. 1111}
\mobile{(000) 000 0000}
\email{uname@email.com}

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{smo}{%
  \par\addvspace{2.5ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}
    {}
    {\leavevmode\llap{#3\hspace{10pt}}}%
    \parbox[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}{\strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{\color{color1}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.95ex}}}%
  \hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
  \parbox[t]{\maincolumnwidth}{\strut\sectionstyle{#2}}
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Coursework}[\includegraphics[height=20pt]{example-image-a}]
\section{Coursework}[\includegraphics[height=20pt]{example-image-b}]
\section{Coursework}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the image must appear between the colored bar and the title, the redefinition is a little bit different:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\firstname{John} 
\familyname{Smith}

\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{Street}{City, St. 1111}
\mobile{(000) 000 0000}
\email{uname@email.com}

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{smo}{%
  \par\addvspace{2.5ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
  \parbox[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}{\strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}  {\color{color1}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.95ex}}}%
  \hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
    \IfNoValueTF{#3}
    {\parbox[t]{\maincolumnwidth}{\strut\sectionstyle{#2}}}
    {\parbox[t]{\maincolumnwidth}{\strut#3\ \sectionstyle{#2}}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Coursework}[\includegraphics[height=20pt]{example-image-a}]
\section{Coursework}[\includegraphics[height=20pt]{example-image-b}]
\section{Coursework}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm ! One question though: why do you need to use `\phantomsection{}` ?

Comment: @Ketouem `\phantomsection` is from the original definition; it's required to create an anchor for cross-references.